# Cannot access redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux, websocket

```
getProps = () => {  // intented by a button click event
   console.log(props.somevalue) // it prints the value
}

socket.listen((data)=>{
   if(data.meta === 'sometrigger'){
      console.log(props.somevalue) // it prints undefined
   }
})
```

Please don't mention how to connect etc... Cuz those both functions are in same scope. All my guess is button event working on the main thread, but the other one is being intented by socket event. Maybe redux dont return the value if its not on the main thread. I am very new at react. I try to get props when the certain method received a trigger message from server via websocket.

Comment: Is the socket listen callback getting removed / re-added after each render? Otherwise it will have the props of the scope at the time it got bound/registered.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli  , Thank you for answer. its a good approach i hadnt think that way. After I read your comment, I took the socket listen callback outside of the useEffect hook. Now it can access the props. But I dont understand what is difference ? How the 'useEffect' hook effects this ?

Comment: `useEffect` is a correct approach, but you need to allow it to re-run when the props you need inside it change. So it is affected by what you pass to the dependency list of the `useEffect`.

Comment: Thank you for all help. That was savior !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.